# Difference between \square{} and \square

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm trying to add a square to my latex document. I'm trying to do this using the `$ \square $` command. However in my latex document I get the error:

> Missing } inserted

If I type `$ \square{} $`, there's no error, but it looks like the output of `$()^2$`. 
Does anyone know how to solve this?
Here's my Preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[applemac]{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{float,rotating}
\usepackage[justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{bibgerm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{floatfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[amssymb,thinspace]{SIunits}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{stmaryrd} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{footnpag}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyph}
\usepackage{boxit}

\begin{document}
$\square$
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, possibly starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: From your description, I'd say that `\square{X}` is supposed to produce "X²", so the command is said to have an "argument", which in this case was "X". If you do only `$\square$`, the command never sees the argument it was expecting and then produces some error. So the correct usage is `\square{<stuff-to-be-squared>}`.

Comment: The `SIunits` package redefines `\square`. See the package documentation for how to handle this. (@PhelypeOleinik)

Comment: An unrelated piece of advice, though: You seem to be using way too many packages. Perhaps you inherited this preamble from somewhere. Recommended practice is only to use packages that you *know* you will need. This leads to fewer problems overall. The line `\usepackage[applemac]{}` makes no sense. Get rid of it.

Comment: you should not be loading `\usepackage{epsfig}` in any document written after 1994, it's just a legacy wrapper for older documents. No need to specify `graphics`

Comment: Thank  You @HaraldHanche-Olsen!

Comment: In a similar vein to the comment about the `epsfig` package, there's no valid rationale for loading the `latexsym` package unless one has to compile a LaTeX document in Latex209-compatibility mode (which is not the case here). There's also no need to load the `amsfonts` package since you're loading the `amssymb` package, which loads the `amsfonts` package automatically. Still another comment: Running `\usepackage[applemac]{}` doesn't look correct at all.

Comment: We need to create a new package `loadall` to load all packages contained in TeX distribution. So the above "MWE" can be made much more compact by calling just one `\usepackage{loadall}`.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer -- If that were done, *nothing* would ever work, and nobody would be able to solve anything.  (I know this is meant as sarcasm, but it really doesn't help.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: OK. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following minimal example replicates the behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[amssymb]{SIunits}

\begin{document}

$\square$

\end{document}
```

Here's what you see in the `.log` when you compile the above document:

```
Option `amssymb' provided! 
Command \square redefined by SIunits package!
```

From the [`SIunits`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunits) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/siunits) about the `amssymb` package option:

> This option redefines the `amssymb` command `\square` to get the desired `SIunits` definition of the command. **Note:** When using this option, the `amssymb` command `\square` can **not** be used.

The redefinition changes `\square` from a symbol into

```
\renewcommand{\square}[1]{\power{#1}{2}}
```

which represents the *square* - *x<sup>2</sup>* - of a number.

---

If you still want to use `\square` from [`amssymb`](//ctan.org/pkg/amssymb), `SIunits` provides the `squaren` package option, that allows you to use `\squaren` instead of `\square` for `siunits`' squaring. That is, `\square` still retains its original definition of a square under `amssymb`.

The suggestion moving forward would be to use the more modern [`siunitx` package](//ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) which provides backwards compatibility with `SIunits`. `siunitx` is under development while development of `SIunits` has stalled since 2007 (in lieu of `siunitx`).

Comment: Sigh.  This is a good example of why it would really be nice to have a comprehensive list of known conflicts.  (Will never happen, I know, but ...)